# Error in Netbeans 8.0 startup

Tags: python, macos, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I recently tried to install the NetBeans plugin described in: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_8

However when I now try and start NetBeans I get a horrendous error that starts like this:

`Warning - could not install some modules: Java Source Queries - None of the modules providing the capability org.netbeans.modules.java.source.queries.spi.QueriesController could be installed. Debugger Core API - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Resource Bundles - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Quick Search API - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Quick Search API - The module named org.netbeans.api.progress.compat8 was needed and not found. XML Core - The module named org.netbeans.api.xml.ui/1 was needed and not found. XML Core - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. XML Multiview Editor - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Common Palette - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Templates - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Settings API - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Auto Update Services - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Auto Update Services - The module named org.netbeans.api.progress.compat8 was needed and not found. REST Application Platform Sample - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. .manifest file Editor Support - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. .diff File Editor Support - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Java Support APIs - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Java Platform - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. User Utilities - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. js-test-driver Wrapper - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. Editor Settings - None of the modules providing the capability org.netbeans.api.editor.settings.implementation could be installed. Editor Library 2 - None of the modules providing the capability org.netbeans.modules.editor.actions could be installed. HTTP Server - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found. HTTP Server-Side Monitor - None of the modules providing the capability org.openide.util.HttpServer$Impl could be installed. HTTP Server-Side Monitor - The module named org.openide.filesystems.compat8 was needed and not found.`

And goes on for pages and pages and pages.

I am running this on OS X.

I have deleted the directories `/Users/<MyUser>/Library/Application Support/NetBeans` and `/Users/<MyUser>/Library/Caches/NetBeans`, as I have seen mentioned in a few places, but I still receive the same error.

This is completely crippling me and preventing me from doing any work, I have no idea what has happened or how to resolve it.

Any help will be massively appreciated.

Comment: Related bug report: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248986

Comment: This happened to me because I tried adding http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand and (forced to) follow their suggestion to add  "Latest Development Plugins" in the update center. Now Netbeans 8.0.2 won't start at all.

Answer (score 1):

Having hit the same impasse, I searched up and down netbeans.org and other sites, provided my logs to bugs https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248986 and https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248291#c5

I exhaustively searched esp. jar and xml files in my %appdata%/Netbeans , sorted by latest modification times, 
and found  files like :

C:\Users\master\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\modules
org-netbeans-modules-jira-rest.jar
org-netbeans-modules-jira-xmlrpc.jar
org-netbeans-modules-scanondemand.jar
etc.

but removing them, or swapping them out with a prior versions, did not help.

Seeing no real solution to even roll back failed updates, at least to get my Netbeans started at all again, I installed the nightly build http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/  elsewhere to compare (on a virtual machine, my "spare" PC).

Continued to compare the fresh installation with my broken installation.
No changes to my broken %appdata% seemed to allow NB to start.

Finally I compared the system-wide installation folders and found that in my broken copy, not only were many .jar files different in size, but some were missing altogether, including this one implicated widely in the startup errors I was getting:

C:\ProgramFiles\NetBeans\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar

That was the strongest hint there won't easily be a "fix"....

It's as if some of the sources in https://forums.netbeans.org/posting.php?mode=quote&p=79922 should never have been allowed to make it into the Update Center. ( http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz in my case....though the chain of dependencies is totally unclear.)

Eventually I overwrote the entire C:\ProgramFiles\NetBeans\ folder from the fresh installation to the broken one, and started successfully.

It needed a few updates, then another restart.
Most of my settings were still there, Dark Theme, recent files list, etc.
Except the Ruby on Rails plugin, which had remained disabled, and I am still trying to re-add and enable it, since it is blocking even the opening of my ROR projects.

So in summary that awful partial workaround was probably equivalent to a re-installation of Netbeans using the development edition (previously I was on 8.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

Please note well that you should not install development plugins (like Python or Scan-on-Demand) into a production installation. Doing so will most likely break your installation and you will be sad.

**If you want to use development plugins, use a development distribution of NetBeans** IDE from 
bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

There *is* currently a **Python plugin made specifically for IDE 8.0.2**; for more on this, visit Geertjan's blog at Oracle: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_81

If you are interested in developing or testing the NEW Python plugin, **join the NetBeans Python Project** at https://netbeans.org/projects/python/pages/Home

Comment: Downvote for multiple reasons: 1) Problem still present in NetBeans Dev 201506220001 and *every* update I've tried since Dec2014. 2) Those already are div distros. 3) In my case, never needed nor bothered/tried installing anything Python in the 1st place, yet problem still present. 4) https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248986 was improperly marked as WONTFIX, while related bugs *closed* as dups of 248986, for the same fallacy, irrelevant reasons mentioned here....As if no one had bothered to examine what's going on or read the bug details, merely citing the words from your post.

Comment: I was answering the original question, which CLEARLY stated the issue was related to installing Python. You presented a different problem in your answer.
YOUR issue is related to the fact that you installed scan-on-demand, which is also a development plugin. NEVER install development plugins (like Python or Scan-on-Demand) into a production installation. I am sorry you had trouble with this. On 28-Dec-2014, I updated the scan-on-demand page to warn users so they wouldn't get "burned" by this. 
And for this you downvoted me?